# didn't fetch data but backend side filtered prefect

Tags: reactjs

How get data from suitable category name in react but didn't fetch data but backend side filtered prefect.

[image]

code

```
     function AllWords(props) {
  const [words, setWords] = useState([])
  const history = useHistory()
  const categoryName = props.match.params.categoryName;

  useEffect(() => { 
      //check Cart type
      if (props.match.params.categoryName === categoryName ) {
         //Fetch Item 
            async function getData() {
                await axios.get(`http://localhost:8070/words12/AllWords/${props.match.params.categoryName}`).then((res) => {
                    setWords(res.data.result) 
                }).catch((error) => {
                alert("Failed to fetch Items")
                })
            }
         getData(); 
        }     
    }, [props])
```

[image]

controller code
[image]

Comment: "didn't fetch data but backend side filtered prefect"? Can you rephrase this part?

Comment: There might be CORS error, could you attach more information about the error you have, in order to be able to help you more? (maybe screenshot from the network tab, console log of the error)